# How to overwrite HTTP response in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have got a custom HttpService that extends Http Angulars:

```
export class HttpService extends Http {
}
```

How to overwrite/catch response?

I tried to do this as follows:

```
return super.request(request, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this)).subscribe({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this like:

```
 const rs = super.request(request, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));

    rs.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Import HttpService class into your child service class where u need.

Create instance for HttpService in constructor and using the instance start using functions in HttpService and you can override those service call